# How to branch when using a remote branch

Tags: git

I come from Perforce and are new to Git. I have a private gitlab server and work with a team. I understand the basic branch concepts of Git, but still struggle to find the default workflow when syncing a branch. Imagine I have the following branch structure

```
$ git branch -a
master
remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
remotes/origin/feature
remotes/origin/my-first-feature
```

`my-first-feature` is derived from `feature`. When I now checkout the branch locally, am I supposed to work directly on this local copy and push it back to this branch on the server? Or should I make another branch locally, which derives from `feature`?

```
$ git checkout my-first-feature
vi do-i-work-directly-here-and-push-back?
```

Comment: You free to do whatever you want to. That is the power of the Git. The question you should ask (yourself or your project manager) is *what process we are using to fulfill the development?* And answer will be exactly what you have to follow.

Comment: [This Q&A](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/165725/git-branching-and-tagging-best-practices) has some really good information about branching strategies. It is from when I was learning how to use Git.

Comment: what's "the" server in a git-context? i have many repositories that don't have any server; i have some repositories that have multiple servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, in git it's more useful to think a bit differently.

Git doesn't really have branches. All it has is a lot of commits, and those commits have parent-child relationships among them. It's also possible for a commit to have two parents (happens when merging). Not sure about more than 2 parents, haven't seen that in practice.

"Branches" in git are really just pointers to commits. They're like human-readable aliases for a specific commit id.

However, by convention, there are a lot of commands that automatically operate on them. For example, when you commit some changes to a branch, git creates a new commit with its parent set to the commit that the branch is currently pointing to. Then it updates that branch to point to the new commit.

Now, when you clone a repository, git not only copies all the commits, but also all the branches. But instead of keeping their names, it changes them to `remotes/origin/<original name>`. This is again just a convention - these branches are in no way special, they're just branches with a name in a specific format.

Now, when you wish to work with one of these branches locally, tradition dictates that you make a local copy of the branch first: `git checkout -b my-first-feature --track remotes/origin/my-first-branch`. There's also a shorthand for this, you can find it in the docs.

What this does is create another, local branch and makes it point to the same commit as the remote branch. In addition, it makes a note at the new local branch which says "this local branch is tracking that remote branch". This has meaning when you push and pull, we'll get to that in a moment. Note that this is still a local operation. Git didn't contact the remote repository to see where its `my-first-branch` is pointing to. It just checks the local `remotes/origin/my-first-branch` branch.

Now you have a new local branch that you can play with as you see fit.

When you do a push operation, git connects to the remote repository and tries to make the remote `my-first-branch` to point to the same commit as your local `my-first-branch`. To do that it uploads all the new commits and tries to update the remote branch pointer. If there are new commits on the server (in `my-first-branch`) it will refuse. It detects this by checking if the commit that your local `my-first-branch` points to is a descendant of the commit that the remote `my-first-branch` is pointing to. If it isn't, you can't push. Then you need to do a pull operation which will get all the new commits, update your local `remotes/origin/my-first-branch` to match that of the server, and then merge `my-first-commit` with `remotes/origin/my-first-commit`. This produces a new commit that is a descendant of the remote `my-first-branch`. Now you can successfully push.

There are also other ways you can play with the commits, but understanding it all is easier if you think in terms of commits rather than branches. Branches are just aliases for convenience. The commit graph is what matters.

Comment: That is a perfect answer! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

> When I now checkout the branch locally, am I supposed to work directly on this local copy and push it back to this branch on the server?

I typically create my feature branches locally and then push them to the remote repo. But it is equally valid to create branches on the remote and then `git fetch` and `git checkout` locally to do your work on that branch. So yes, working directly on the fetched feature branch is a good way to do your work.

Comment: Thanks for the reassurance!

Answer (score 1):

When using Git you are correct in having a branch off of the main "feature" branch. Some would rename this to develop then branch off of the develop branch for your"my-first-feature".

You should not branch off of your local branch due to the fact that if you pull/update your local "my-first-feature" branch merge issues would occur.

1. branch off of feature
2. create branch "my-first-feature"
3. When ready push local back to "my-first-feature" branch
4. After satisfied with all changes merge with "feature/develop" branch

Hope that answers your questions

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Is it uncommon to have several `develop-foo`, `develop-bar`,... branches on the server which all derive from `develop`? We have different teams and I was hoping having seperate branches would be common, since it follows our current workflow

Comment: P.S. To point (2), create branch "my-first-feature", you mean on the server or only locally?

Comment: @DanielStephens 1st comment: it is common practice to have devlop as a second "master" branch then as you describe have develop-foo branch etc.2nd comment: on server try not to make branches on local machine. For example if you create a branch "foo" on local and someone creates branch "bar" on server when you go to push you branch to "develop-foo" you will remove branch "bar" 's code. This results in bad merging